# aspnet_compiler can not see my class

Tags: aspnet-compiler

I have a web application project, which compiles fine using VS2008. However each time, I try to compile it with aspnet_compiler it fails and is not able to see my class, which I have placed in my code folder. Why is the aspnet_compiler not able to see my class and how can I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: We are going to need more information in order to help.  What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: MyFile.ascx.vb(73): error BC30451: Name 'ElmahHelper' is not declared. However the ElmahHelper.vb is in my code folder and is added in the visual studio project.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the namespace is referenced appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the .vb file in your project, look under the proporties palette and make sure that Build Action is set to Compile.